# How to mock external requests using aiohttp?

Tags: python, aiohttp

I'm trying to mock a single request to an external URL but in the documentation exists just examples to internal request (starting with '/'), it's impossible to add routers who not start with '/' on the current version of aiohttp.
I'm using pytest and pytest-aiohttp, here are an example of the request code:

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(client):
   async with client.get('http://python.org') as resp:
       return resp.status, (await resp.text())

async def main():
   async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
       html = await fetch(client)
       print(html)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

The kind of assertion that I want to do is very simple, like check the status code, the headers, and the content.

Comment: What are you trying to test?

Comment: I'm trying to mock the response of an external service, and test my code with the possible results for that request.

Answer (score 1):

You can patch (using asynctest.patch) your `ClientSession`. But in this case you need to implement simple `ResponseContextManager` with `.status, async .text() (async .json()), etc.` methods and attrs.

Comment: I thought that was an easier way to do that... once that is basic.

Comment: Yes, you can just patch response. But if you do this in such way you will have ability to check many another things for example check with which args you request was called.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment (below your question), you say you're actually looking to mock aiohttp responses. For that, I've been using the 3rd-party library `aioresponses`: https://github.com/pnuckowski/aioresponses

I use it for integration testing, where it seems better than directly mocking or patching aiohttp methods.

I made it into a little pytest fixture like so:

```
@pytest.fixture
def aiohttp_mock():
    with aioresponses() as aioresponse_mock:
        yield aioresponse_mock
```

which I can then call like an aiohttp client/session: `aiohttp_mock.get(...)`

Edit from the future: We actually went back to mocking `aiohttp` methods because `aioresponses` currently lacks the ability to verify the args that were used in the call. We decided that verifying the args was a requirement for us.